# Dynamically change number of loop iteration

Tags: loops, iteration, combinations, brute-force

I am trying to generate combinations and to verify a given hash. The pseudocode I used as

```
for i= 'a' to 'z'
{
    for j= 'a' to 'z'
    {
        for k= 'a' to 'z'
        {
            for l= 'a' to 'z'
            {
                hashStr = MD5(i+j+k+l);
                if(hashStr = targetHash)
                {
                    print "Match Found"
                    Exit
                }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

With the above pseudocode, I could generate combinations with fixed length 4 as

```
aaaa
aaab
aaac
...
zzzz
```

Possilby could someone helpme out to write logic in such a way that, one could easily change the length without adding extra iterative for loop.

Comment: [Recursion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested by @TJ, recursion is probably the most straight forward approach.

#### JavaScript

```
var chars = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';

function loop(prefix, length) {
    if (length > 0) {
        for (var i = 0; i < chars.length; i++) {
            loop(prefix + chars.charAt(i), length - 1);
        }
    } else if (length == 0) {
        var hashStr = prefix;
        // ......
        // Your logic goes here         
        // ......
    } else {
        // length should always be non-negative
    }
}

function theLoop(length) {
    loop('', length);
}
```

Simply call `theLoop(l)` to looping over all strings of length `l` in order to find collision.

#### Java Code

```
void loop(int length) {
    loop("", length);
}

void loop(String prefix, int length) {
    if (length > 0) {
        for (char i = 'a'; i <= 'z'; i++) {
            loop(prefix + i, length - 1);     // concatenate prefix with char (i)
        }
    } else if (length == 0) {
        String hashStr = prefix;
        // ......
        // Your logic goes here         
        // ......
    } else {
        // length should always be non-negative
    }
}
```

Simply call `loop(l)` to looping over all strings of length `l` in order to find collision.

Comment: Thanks, I am just learning recursion. I am implementing it using javascript.

Comment: I have also added the code in JavaScript for your reference